# Generate all the possible arrangement of a set of pieces on a board

Tags: algorithm

I am wondering what would be the best approach to generate all the possible combinaison of placement in a battleship game with the following constraints:
- the board has R rows and C columns
- on the board should be place a set of L ships
- each ship has size (number of slot they would use on the board)
- a ship can be place on the board horizontally or vertically
- 2 ships cannot overlap

for example, considering a 10x10 board and a set of 5 ships:

- L1 : 5 slots
- L2 : 3 slots
- L3 : 3 slots
- L4 : 3 slots
- L5 : 2 slots

How to generate a set of all the possible board arrangement.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: can Battleships be adjacent to each other?

Comment: @TomerW yes they can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you want to enumerate the arrangements rather than counting them, and the number of the arrangements is exponential in the size of the board, and the number of ships is small in the traditional game, you cannot do better than just brute-forcing it through trying to place each ship in every possible position it fits and back-tracking.

If you have *a lot of ships*, like that your board is almost full, or you are only interested in counting the number of arrangements, then you can try using a [ZDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-suppressed_decision_diagram) to get an exponential boost (though the running time might still be exponential).

**EDIT:** To handle same-size ships efficiently, you have to consider their multiplicity. I.e. first group the ship into a vector `u[i]` of "how many ship of form `i` we have":

- If you loop over cells then you maintain a vector `v[i]` of "how many ship of form `i` have already been placed". For each cell you try to put the ship of form `i` iff `v[i] < u[i]`, and if it fits then you increment `v[i]` and recurse to the next cell.
- If you loop over ship then after you placed ship of form `i` at some cell then you recurse putting the rest of ships of the same form only at cells which are 'after' that cell that have already been placed. When all ship of form `i` have been placed on the board you move to placing the next form from cell zero.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed I wish to enumerate all the possible outcome . What puzzles me is "how to" do the brute-force thing in a smart way and avoid to explore "duplicate" since you can have several identical ships